# How can a function not be one to one and be a function?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

My understanding of the definition of a function

Given any x, there is only one y that can be paired with x

My understanding of a 1 to 1 function

Given any y, there is only one x that can be paired with y

How are these definitions not the same?

I don't understand because it seems like 1 to 1 just describes what the definition of a function is.

Comment: Having one output per input, and having one input per output are very different things.

Comment: Take $y=x^2$. Any $x$ produces a definite $y$, but there are for example two values of $x$ that produce $y=9$, namely $x=3$ and $x=-3$. So $x^2$ is not a one to one function. It is definitely a function.

Comment: If you draw a the relation as two sets with arrows going from domain elements to range elements, then being a "function" requires that you can't have two arrows going from one point in the domain to two different points in the range. Being "one-to-one" requires that you can't have two arrows going from two different points in the domain to the same point in the range.

Comment: I don't like the way your textbook uses the word "paired".  In real life, when you take some things and "pair" them together, each thing ends up in just one unique pair.  If that were the way the definition of "function" worked, then all functions _would_ be one-to-one.  But that is not the way a good definition of function works.

A good definition would emphasize the directionality of functions, such as, "each $x$ maps to just one image, $y$".  But as you have seen already, although each individual $x$ can map to only one $y$, several different values of $x$ might all map to the same $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can be in the same place at 2 different times, but you can't be in 2 places at once.
Given any x, there is only one y that can be paired with x, but it is possible that there are multiple $x$s associated with a single $y$ (e.g if $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}|f(x)=x^2$ then $f(-x)=f(x)$)